# Android Command Line Error

Tags: android, command-line

Ok I am trying to make a project from a command line ( not really sure how my book doesn't say WHAT OR WHERE the command line is ) and when I try to run android.bat from the windows command prompt I get this error telling me that it checked for Java 64 bit and it wasn't found , then it checked for Java 32 and it wasn't found. The thing is I just installed Java SE 32 bit last night from Oracles site.

In Control Panel Programs I see :

Java (TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 23  Oracle 141 MB 1.6.0.230

Why is Android telling me it's not found?

Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit 
Q6600 Intell quad core 
4GBs DDR2 Ram
Nvidia 8800 GTS 
Asus D2X
Gigabyte EP45-DSL3R

**UPDATE: Ok now I get this error :**

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

G:\Programming\android-sdk_r08-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>android create
project --target 2 --path ./FirstApp --activity FirstApp --package
Error: Missing argument for flag --package.

Usage:
  android [global options] create project [action options]

Global options:
  -v --verbose  Verbose mode: errors, warnings and informational messages are pr
inted.
  -h --help     Help on a specific command.
  -s --silent   Silent mode: only errors are printed out.

Action "create project":
  Creates a new Android project.
Options:
  -n --name     Project name
  -t --target   Target ID of the new project [required]
  -p --path     The new project's directory [required]
  -k --package  Android package name for the application [required]
  -a --activity Name of the default Activity that is created [required]

G:\Programming\android-sdk_r08-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>apt.tutorial
**strong text**

Comment: `not really sure how my book doesn't say WHAT OR WHERE the command line is` Then maybe you shouldn't try to build from the command line and just use eclipse?

Comment: Try defining `JAVA_HOME` to be where Java is installed, and make sure the Java commands (`java`, `javac`, etc.) are in your `PATH`. Those commands are usually in the `bin` directory inside of wherever Java is installed.

Comment: @Falmari Yes I have eclipse set up with the Android SDK and would prefer that method, but my Android 2 book is teachign how to make a project from the command line so I decided to try it out.

Comment: @Common Heres the line the book uses no mention of home any where: android create project --target 2 --path ./FirstApp --activity FirstApp --package
apt.tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Heres the line the book uses no mention of home any where: android create project --target 2 --path ./FirstApp --activity FirstApp --package apt.tutorial

That is one of my books.

Step #2 of Tutorial 1 has you check your Java environment and set up your `PATH`. This occurs before Step #4 of Tutorial 1, where you use `android create project`. AFAIK, that should have been sufficient. However, I do not use 64-bit Windows, and so I have no idea if there are any other things you need to do to get Java working there.

If you have further questions about this tutorial, please join the [cw-android Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android) and ask there.

Please note that the version of the book you are using (Version 1.0 or the 1st Edition) is about 18 months old at the time of this writing, so you may encounter some challenges along the way. In particular, the latter half of the book is dominated by a sample Twitter client, which will no longer work due to the 2010 modification in Twitter authentication models. I have [some instructions](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/patchy) for how to try to patch the book, in essence, to use identi.ca, another microblogging client.

**UPDATE**

As you noted, I had the wrong book in mind. Here are the steps to set up your `PATH`, as described in *Android Programming Tutorials*:

You should also be sure to add the directory for the Java commands to your `PATH` by:

1. Finding where the Java commands are (e.g., `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin`).
2. Go to your Control Panel (Start > Settings > Control Panel).
3. Double-click on the System applet.
4. Click the Advanced tab.
5. Click the Environment Variables button.
6. If there is a `PATH` value in the User variables area at the top, add
   your path to the end by double-clicking the existing one, scrolling
   to the end, typing a semicolon (;) and the path from step #1 above.
   If there is no such `PATH` value, click the New button, fill in PATH as
   the Variable name and the path from step #1 above as the Variable
   value.

Comment: Actually this version is Beginning Android 2 by Mark L Murphey , the book was made this year 2010

Comment: @jchase520: Oops. I had forgotten that I had used `apt.tutorial` there as well as in _Android Programming Tutorials_, where most of the `apt.tutorial` stuff resides. That book definitely assumes prior Java experience and a working Java environment. And my last name does not have an 'e' in it. :-)

Comment: :) Sorry my friend! Well I'm on Chapter 6 of my Java book from Head First, I also have prior experience with C++ , C , HTML , XHTML , CSS and Small / Pawn. So this isn't my first language but I'm reading both books at once lol

Comment: @jchase520: FWIW, I am rewriting all of the front matter of that book for its next edition under my own brand (_The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_), so this stuff should improve over time. I hope the book proves useful!

Comment: Ok I have added PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin to my enviroment variables , then tried to run the android create project --target 2 --path ./FirstApp --activity FirstApp --package apt.tutorial and still received the same error about no Java

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


G:\Programming\android-sdk_r08-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>android create
project --target 2 --path ./FirstApp --activity FirstApp --package apt.tutorial

Comment: WARNING: Java not found in your path.
Checking if it's installed in C:\Program Files\Java instead (64-bit).
Checking if it's installed in C:\Program Files\Java instead.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Comment: @jchase520: If you did not do so already, open a fresh Command Prompt, as local environment variable changes do not take immediate effect. Then, try running just `java` at the `C:` prompt. If that fails, then there is still something wrong with your `PATH`.

Comment: Ok when I type in java it gives me all the usage options for the Java command

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>Java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>

Comment: @jchase520: That error is self-explanatory -- you did not include the last parameter. Per the book, it is `android create project --target 2 --path ./FirstApp --activity FirstApp --package apt.tutorial`, and you do not have the `apt.tutorial` part.

Comment: ak , ok i got it working now! My appologies you were right :)

Comment: Ok thank you for the help every one! i'm back to the book now! :)